# IIS SMTP server sending emails multiple times

Tags: iis, iis-7, smtp

I am having a problem with the SMTP server on a Windows server 2008 box.  Every Thursday morning, the server decides to send the same 2000+ emails to the same person.  There is nothing in the code that does this.  Has anyone ever run into this?  If so, how did you resolve this?

Thanks

Edit:  I am just a programmer for a client.  This is their server that was bought through GoDaddy.  My expertise in server setup and maintenance is limited.

Here is part of the log file from this morning.

```
2013-03-07 08:04:22 127.0.0.1 blahWebsite SMTPSVC1 BLAHWEBSITE 127.0.0.1 0 EHLO - +BLAHWebsite 250 0 185 16 0 SMTP - - - -
2013-03-07 08:04:22 127.0.0.1 blahWebsite SMTPSVC1 BLAHWEBSITE 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<blah@blah.com> 250 0 47 34 0 SMTP - - - -
2013-03-07 08:04:22 127.0.0.1 blahWebsite SMTPSVC1 BLAHWEBSITE 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<blahrec@blah.com> 250 0 39 36 0 SMTP - - - -
2013-03-07 08:04:22 127.0.0.1 blahWebsite SMTPSVC1 BLAHWEBSITE 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - <BLAHWEBSITEvkbk6MQA0002354d@BLAHWEBSITE> 250 0 124 435 78 SMTP - - - -
```

Comment: More information is needed to help.  Are there any scheduled tasks around this time?  What do you see in the log files?  Are you able to provide us with headers?  Are the 2000+ emails someone syncing a mailbox?

Comment: There are no scheduled tasks.  I will edit the question with part of the logs.  I am not sure what headers your talking about.  And no it's not someone syncing a mailbox

Comment: can you take a string of words from the email and then run a find/replace program on all the files on the server and see if you can locate a script that contains the string being emailed out?  Maybe that will help you identify the source.

Answer (score 1):

Who are the emails coming from.
Are they sent to the person specifically?
I think you should be able to look in your exchange queues to help figure it out.
or at least help trouble shoot more.

Comment: The emails are sent from the same email, which is an email that was setup by the owner of the server.  I have access to the mail logs, but I really don't know what I am looking at in those.

Comment: It sounds like he (owner of the server) may have set up logs to be forwarded to a distro group for IT that this guy is possibly the only one in? That's just the feel I get from it. Is the owner of the server not around any more? What I would do first is check what distros this guy is a member of and make sure there isn't anything fishy that looks like he's the only member or a member of something he shouldn't be.

Comment: The server is through GoDaddy.  The client I am working for pays for the server.  I am still in contact with them.  Nothing fishy.  Its probably some setting that I need to change that I don't know about.

Comment: There has to be an IT guy at the your client company who you can talk to that knows more about this. From what I understand of GoDaddy they will give you a Domain and Host your website for you at the most but they don't have servers that can host an exchange server. Which is what you make it sound like they are doing.